# QGIS 3.0 Girona using profile tool, get python error

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, profile

I have a raster layer (LIDAR data) selected. On releasing the mouse button, and before any rubber band starts, I get this error:
Message log:

2018-03-09T16:19:08 WARNING Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/John/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\profiletool\tools\ptmaptool.py", line 78, in moved
                self.profiletool.rubberband.addPoint(QgsPoint(self.pointstoDraw[i][0],self.pointstoDraw[i][1]))
            TypeError: QgsRubberBand.addPoint(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsPoint'

Can you help, please?

Answer (score 2):

I uninstalled the plugin and donwload last zip from web page and it work again. The link is in the bug tracker in the plugin window in Qgis 3.

Comment: Thank you Marco. I just uninstalled the plugin and reinstalled using the plugin manager, but still have the same problem (QGIS 3.0.1 now).

Comment: It worked for me in Qgis 3.20 (Odense)

Answer (score 1):

Based on Kantan answer, here is how to do using git:

- Uninstall Profile Tool plugin, then close QGIS3
- Open a git-enabled terminal, go to folder %User%\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins (or other QGIS3 plugin folder if different)
- Type in terminal

  git clone https://github.com/etiennesky/profiletool.git

  cd profiletool

  git fetch origin pull/48/head:qgis3_compatibility

  git checkout qgis3_compatibility
- Open QGIS 3. It should work

Comment: I had the same issue and tried this method, but it didn't work. It may require additional software or only work on some operating systems.  downloading the zip file and copying it into the plugins directory did, work.

Comment: Well, I installed git, but Windows command didn't recognise git as a command. Tried in git command window, did the clone OK but >git fetch origin... generated 
C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins>git fetch origin pull/48/head:qgis3_compatibility
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git. So I'm still stuck!

Comment: user30578 : I forgot the "cd profiletool" line after the "git clone", sorry. Can you try the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin hasn't been updated yet for Qgis 3.0. 
I was able to make it work using the proposed merges in the [gitHub repository](https://github.com/etiennesky/profiletool/pull/48)

First, locate where the plugin is saved (%User%\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\profiletool by default)

Then, you want to replace those files with the ones proposed for the pull.

Either edit them manually or download and replace them all.

After that the plugin worked as it used to in Qgis 2.x.